# Add Image to a TreeView loaded from a directory

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Treeview` that loads the Tree of a selected directory. Now I would like to make the directories have a folder image and the files a file image. Both Folder and File images are in a `imagelist` connected to my `treeview`. How would I adjust the following code to do this?

```
    private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeview, string path)
    {
        treeview.Nodes.Clear();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        treeview.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
    }


    private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
        }


        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
        }
        return directoryNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the `Directory image` has index of `0` in your `imagelist` and `File image` has index of `1` in your imagelist:

```
private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name){ImageIndex=0};

    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
    }


    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name){ImageIndex=1});
    }
    return directoryNode;
}
```